# What are the common sensors/ways that reverse thrust is measured for turbines?

Tags: turbine, thrust, thrust-reverser, sensors, measurement

I am looking for a sensor to measure reverse thrust on a small hobby turbine engine, a jetcat p100-rx. I did not find clear ways industry measures reverse thrust from previous searches online and was wondering what has been done before/with what the data was captured with.

Comment: I was looking to get an accurate read-out of thrust diverted by the thrust reverser for when the design is complete. I was thinking of a clamshell design that would move into place to reverse the thrust.  Thank you, I will check out the paper you linked!